# Matlab video reader - draw disk on objects

Tags: matlab

i try to draw a disk on objects in video (the object are cars are move on road from left to right).

my code:

```
obj = VideoReader('Cars.avi');
get(obj)

im = read(obj,71);
nframes = get(obj,'NumberOfFrames');

sedisk = strel('disk',10);
im_new = imopen(im,sedisk);
stats = regionprops(im_new);
area_array = [stats.Area];

im2 = read(obj,1);
figure,imagesc(im2);
for i=1:nframes-1
    stats(i).Centroid
    frame = read(obj,i);
    imshow(frame);
end
```

i see the frames but not the disk on the cars, why it's not working? 
maybe something in the logic is wrong?

thank's everyone

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `regionprops` code into the for loop, and plot the regions over the image.

- Start by following MATLAB [regionprops documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html)

I built a sample code with `traffic.avi` as input file.
`traffic.avi` file comes with my MATLAB installation (in folder `toolbox/images/imdata/`).

Here is a code sample (please read the comments):

```
clear
close all

%obj = VideoReader('Cars.avi');
obj = VideoReader('traffic.avi');

nframes = get(obj, 'NumberOfFrames');

%sedisk = strel('disk', 10);
sedisk = strel('disk', 2); %Smaller disk fits traffic.avi (you can keep sedisk = strel('disk', 10))

%Read first image (assume no cars). In your code you can keep: im = read(obj,71);
im1 = read(obj,1);

for i = 2:nframes
    im = read(obj, i);

    imshow(im); %Show the frame

    %Subtract frame form the first frame - assume the cars will pop up in the difference image.
    diff_im = uint8(abs(double(im) - double(im1)));

    I = rgb2gray(diff_im); %Convert to grayscale image
    BW = imbinarize(I); %Convert to binary image.

    im_new = imopen(BW, sedisk);
    stats = regionprops('table', im_new, 'Centroid', 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength'); %MATLAB documentation code sample

    %imshow(im_new);

    if (~isempty(stats))
        %stats(i).Centroid
        centers = stats.Centroid; %Get centers (MATLAB documentation code sample)

        %Get radius of the circles (MATLAB documentation code sample).
        diameters = mean([stats.MajorAxisLength stats.MinorAxisLength],2);
        radii = diameters/2;

        %Plot the circles on the displayed video frame.
        hold on
        viscircles(centers,radii);
        hold off
    end

    pause(0.1); %Pause 0.1 seconds
end
```

The code is not marking the cars accurately (just demonstrates the stages).

Here is a sample frame:
[image]